# Create list of objects from reading excel .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an .xlsx file like the one below:

[image]

I need to read this file and create a list of the customers class where the name field corresponds to the first column and the email field corresponds to the second. Below is the class customers:

```
namespace ReadExcelAndInsertMySQL.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying the following, but as it is, a list is created with the size corresponding to the number of lines, but repeating the last element of the spreadsheet:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using ReadExcelAndInsertMySQL.Domain.Entities;
using ReadExcelAndInsertMySQL.Infra.Data.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\\Arquivos\\clientes.xlsx");
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
            {
                var workbook = package.Workbook;
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
                int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
                Customers customer = new Customers();
                
                for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        if (col == 1)
                        {
                            customer.Name = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            customer.Email = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                        }                        
                    }

                    customers.Add(customer);
                }
                customers.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue, because you have initialized the customer once before loop on rows, to correct this, you should initialize the customer for each row, like the following code :

```
...
for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
{
    Customers customer = new Customers();
    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
    {
        if (col == 1)
        {
            customer.Name = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            customer.Email = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }

    customers.Add(customer);
}
customers.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name}, {x.Email}");
});
...
```

Note that, `Console.WriteLine(x)` will not display the value of customer, you should specify `Name` and `Email`.

I hope you find this helpful.